# Use normal delete-region with backspace in markdown-mode

Tags: key-bindings, use-package, markdown-mode

I would like to use the "normal" behaviour for `<backspace>` in `markdown-mode`. That is, instead of calling `markdown-exdent-or-delete`, I would like to call `cua-delete-region`. So I tried this rebinding (using `bind-key`):

```
(use-package markdown-mode
    :ensure t
  :mode ("\\.\\(m\\(ark\\)?down\\|md\\)$" . markdown-mode)
  :config (bind-key "<backspace>" 'cua-delete-region)
)
```

But I get no changes. (Or rather I do: but for some strange reason only in the minibuffer!)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the mode-map for which you want to modify the `<backspace>` binding:

```el
(bind-key "<backspace>" #'cua-delete-region markdown-mode-map)
```

*What you were doing was overriding the binding in the global map. So you would see your custom binding effective only in the places where any other minor or major mode is NOT mapping the `<backspace>` key.*

Comment: Thanks. What's the `#` for? I didn't find it in the documentation.

Comment: It's primarily for a good coding practice. When you are using a quoted function name, it's good to always sharp quote it: http://endlessparentheses.com/get-in-the-habit-of-using-sharp-quote.html