# Delete marked region with py-electric-backspace py-electric-delete

Tags: python, region, mark, elpy, deletion

In my `python-mode` the `backspace` and `delete` keys gets remapped to `py-electric-backspace`, etc. This breaks the behaviour set by the variable `delete-active-region`.

Is there a way to unify the behaviour so that when I mark a region and press `delete` it will actually delete the region and if unmarked act as dedicated by `py-electric-backspace`?

A related question has been posted [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9693/use-normal-delete-region-with-backspace-in-markdown-mode), but not completely applicable.

EDIT:
This has been fixed in the latest `python-mode` package by *Andreas* (See comments below)

Comment: Sounds reasonable, thanks for the suggestion. Made a feature-request for it. Please follow up here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode/+bug/1453384

Comment: fixed meanwhile

Answer (score 1):

The normal way to fix this is to fix `py-electric-backspace` to check `use-region-p` and `delete-active-region` and handle them as expected.

IOW, I'd submit a bug report to the maintainers of the package.